# Wakanda 2.2.1 Enterprise Server DataBrowser

Tags: console, admin, wakanda

Regarding the 2.2.1 Wakanda Enterprise Server, I'm looking for basic guidance regarding some of the features that were more easily accessed with prior Studio versions (buttons):

Data Browser - using the simply CRUD example from Wakanda.  Following address does not yield a Data Browser:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/walib/dataBrowser/index.html.  Tried port 8081 as well, the server is published on 8080.

Administration Console.  Possibly due to a license key issue; but should I get the full administration console functionality as with prior versions?  I am seeing only a small subset of features on the admin console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy workaround for the databrowser. I copied the whole walib-Directory in an folder (eg. WebFolder) in the backend folder. In the app.waProject in the backend i have

```
<type name="backend" />
    <folder path="./WebFolder/">
    <tag name="webFolder"/>
    </folder>
```

Now I can call it with 127.0.0.1:8081/walib/dataBrowser/index.html
I don't know if this is a good solution, but as long as it works and just for debugging ...

Answer (score 0):

Data Browser is made with WAF of Wakanda V1 and is removed since V2 no longer supports WAF. The V2 CRUD example using Angular is available in latest [Wakanda doc](https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-data-cs).

The Administration Console, aka Admin Dashboard in v2, has received an update in v2 with more features include:

1. Display the running solution basic information.
2. Run WakandaDB maintenance actions: run, verify and restore.
3. Schedule tasks (CRON jobs): create, update, schedule and remove.
4. Analyze your tasks execution (calendar, output, statistics..).

You will need an enterprise license to access admin dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/.

Comment: The data browser from the prior versions was an important tool for testing and development and especially for finding root issues to complex problems around relationships.  Please consider delivering an angularized version or please recommend an off the shelf alternative.

Comment: Hamza has floated the idea of a simple data browser built using Angular. But it will not be the team's top priority. If you have a real use case that requires a data browser. Please feel free to comment under this thread: https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/164, or start a new feature request on github issues.

Comment: The Data Browser was a really high value tool.  A lot of work went into its development, that is clear.  As I approach completion of my front end rewrites (Angular), I'm "feeling" the gap more and more due to the absence of the databrowser.  I tried the above technique, and it tries to render but is not successful.