# Wakanda data browser (V1) in V 2.4.0

Tags: database, browser, wakanda

I've been using Wakanda since version 1. x and have been hesitating for a long time to test the newer versions because they no longer have a data browser. Now I have installed the latest version and installed a webfolder in the backend. Here I copied the complete WALIB directory and declared the Webfolder as active webfolder. Now I can use the URL "localhost: 8081/walib/dataBrowser/index. html" to access the Databrowser website, but 2 calls end with a 404 error:

1. "http://127.0.0.1:8081/db/walib/dataBrowser/index.package.json~waf-build.js?path=WALIB"

and

2. "http://127.0.0.1:8081/db/walib/dataBrowser/index.package.json~waf-build.css?path=WALIB"

It looks like the tilde is causing the problem. 
How can I solve the problem, do I still have to make an adjustment somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

@MyemaHMN has posted a solution that worked in this thread: [Wakanda 2.2.1 Enterprise Server DataBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254941/wakanda-2-2-1-enterprise-server-databrowser). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I've read that already. I did it as described there, but I just had problems with the 404 bug because of the tilde ~ in the URL.
I am using the 2.4.0 community version of Wakanda.
When I look at the network actions in the chrome debugger, both URLs return a 404 error, even if I take the URL addresses and call the browser, I get the 404 error. If I replace the tilde ~ then the request works, but the response from the server is not the same as the content of the system where everything works normally with tilde ~

Comment: Other than the 404 error with tilde, are you able to use the data browser?

Comment: I don't know, because of the 404 error the UI doesn't reload, because the two scripts don't return the lists with the widgets (JS files) and the CSS files to be loaded. In the old version (I am using 1.1.3) the two calls deliver the complete JS and the complete CSS for the database browser (at least looks like this to me)

Answer (score 0):

The tilde does not seem to be the problem. In my solution I have the same call like:
http://127.0.0.1:8081/walib/dataBrowser/index.package.json~waf-build.css?path=WALIB
and it is working. 
I guess it is the issue is the /db/ directory in the link. Where does it come from? The walib-directory is expected to be immediately under the webfolder.
Check the directory structure and check the app.waProject in relation to that.

Comment: The "db" directory was only an attempt, at first I also had the walib directory directly under the web directory, the result was the same.
The link works in the way that there is no 404 error, for example with a # instead of the tilde. Then, however, not with the right return value.
In the meantime, I have given up trying to make the Data Browser work. I make my own database browser following the old one from Wakanda based on Angular 5 with PrimeNG components and the Angular-Wakanda client. This is more efficient in the long run and I can build everything as I need it.

Comment: As written in the comment before, I have now created a new data browser which is available here: 
[Wakanda Data Browser](https://github.com/MtiQS/Wakanda-Databrowser)